# MATLAB Hermite interpolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Anyone know where I can find the Hermite interpolation algorithm in MATLAB. Which Hermite interpolation algorithm solves this?

I need to calculate a polynomial. Example:

```
x=[1,2,3];
y=[0.5,1,12]  
y'=[1,0.2,0.9]
y''=[0.1,0.6,0.8]
x2=[1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5];
polynom=hermit_interpolation(x,y,y',y'',x2); % i need the polynom to
y2=polyval(polynom,x2);
plot(x2,y2);
```

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 2):

There is the pchip command documented [here](http://www.mathworks.it/help/techdoc/ref/pchip.html).

Comment: Note that `pchip()` is a method for specific variety of cubic Hermite interpolation. I gave a discussion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/51412).