# Interpolation method that does never overshoot

Tags: interpolation, spline

To implement a system that will control hardware, I need an interpolation between points on a graph that does never overshoot.
By overshooting I mean that between two points there may be no y-result that has a higher value than either of thew two points.

First I thought that "monotone cubic interpolation" might be what I need, however after implementation I found that this isn't always the case. After researching, I found that this only reduces overshooting, doesn't prevent it entirely. That can also be seen here, I think: [Implementation of Monotone Cubic Interpolation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45218/implementation-of-monotone-cubic-interpolation) )

So what other algorithms/formulas could fulfill this requirement?

Comment: Linear interpolation doesn't overshoot. If that doesn't work, please list what additional criteria you need to satisfy.

Comment: @Bungo You are right! An additional criteria is needed. Hm, I'm not a matimatician, so simply put I want a curve that's as smooth as possible and also monotone between two points.
Maybe the following definition makes sense: The second derivation on the curve shall be overall minimal. Linear interpolation has a very high second derivation at every point where direction changes.

Comment: The monotone cubic interpolation that I'm familiar with (the Fritsch-Carlson method) is guaranteed not to overshoot the data. If your implementation does overshoot, either you have implemented something that is not truly monotone, or there is a bug in your implementation.

Comment: There is a method called Barycentric Lagrange interpolation.  There are plenty of libraries available for it.

Comment: Indeed there was a dumb implementation mistake x.x Oh well, sorry for wasting your all time!  Barycentric Lagrange interpolation sounds interesting too though.

Answer (score 2):

If you can do without the 'strict' interpolation criterion (saying that the curve must pass precisely through the knot points), you can use a b-spline without prefiltering - simply use the knot points you have as the spline's coefficients. The b-spline is bound to the convex hull of it's coefficients, so it can't overshoot the range if it's coefficients aren't ever out-of-bounds. But omitting the prefilter will 'spoil' the interpolation criterion, and the resulting curve will not pass exactly through your data points - it will appear slightly 'smoothed'. Oftentimes, though, this is quite acceptable, and it will never overshoot.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Maybe it's not clear to a bot ;)

Answer (score 0):

One option is use a monotone cubic interpolation but always check the values of the points on both sides, and if the value exceeds one of the two y values, just go with that y value instead.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately that results in quite a "corner" at the point where it would start to overshoot.
"Bungo" u there is right though, I need to specify an idditional criteria. One moment.

Answer (score 0):

you want "smoothstep" or "smootherstep" you can derive them from differential equations or function intuition, but basically these shape linear interpolation so that the derivative is 0 at the ends, and concatenating these curves results in continuous first derivatives for smoothstep, and both first and second for smootherstep.

linear: lerp(a, b, t)

smoothstep: lerp(a, b, 3t^2 - 2t^3)

smootherstep: lerp(a, b, 6t^5 - 16t^4 + 10t^3)

lerp being a shorthand for a + (b-a)*t

these do lose some of the nice visual properties of the cubic interpolation - they only sample 2 points, not 4, but they does meet the criteria you specify, never overshooting and being continuous and smooth to first or second order.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).